# Proof that $x^2 \geq 0$ for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone please provide me with the proof of the following statement:

$x^2 \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Are you supposed to show this directly from the axioms of real numbers?

Answer (score 3):

From axiomatic property of Real numbers, if $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b\geq0$, then $a.b\geq0$.
So, When $x$ is non-negative i.e $x \geq 0$, there is no chance of getting a negative value when it is multiplied by another non-negative number($=x$) to have $x^2$.

And, when $x$ is negative i.e $x<0$, we can simply write $x=(-1)|x|$.
Now, $x^2=(-1)(-1)|x||x|$.
Multiplication between two negative numbers always result in positive value.
So, here $(-1)(-1)$ is positive.
Thus,$x^2$ will always give non-negative value whether $x$ is non-negative or negative Real number.

Comment: Might be helpful to say, that the implication $a,b>0 \Rightarrow a \cdot b > 0$ is an axiomatic property of the real numbers (the order axioms). Hence the phrase "there is no chance of getting a negative value" is kind of confusing.

Comment: Also I think that the negative case should be deduced with elementary steps from the ordering axiom and the group structure of $(\mathbb R, \cdot)$ instead of using the more high level decomposition $x = (-1) \left| x \right|$.

Comment: "Multiplication between two negative numbers always result in positive value." - This is not an axiom. You are omitting the interesting part of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $\mathbb R$ is an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Total_order). Since $\leq$ is a total order, we have $0\leq x$ or $x\leq 0$. The case $0\leq x$ was already discussed in the other answer, so let us consider the case $x\leq 0$:

According to the axioms of ordered fields we have that $x-x\leq 0-x$, i.e. $0\leq -x$. That being said, $0\leq(-x)^2=x^2$ (if $F$ is a field, then $xy=(-x)(-y)$ for all $x,y\in F$) according to the first case.